# Group by index giving keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Sample Data]

I'm trying to understand how the group by function works and I'm trying to group the low.2018 column with the State column

My code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("datasets/Minimum Wage Data.csv",encoding='latin')

df.to_csv("datasets/Minwage.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
act_min_wage=pd.DataFrame()

for name,group in df.groupby("State"):
    if act_min_wage.empty:
        group.set_index("Year",inplace=True)
        act_min_wage=group[["Year","Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name})
    else:
        group.set_index("Year",inplace=True)
        act_min_wage=act_min_wage.join(group[["Year","Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name}))

act_min_wage.head()
```

KeyError: "['Year'] not in index" is the error I get, Even though Year is a valid column in the given table. What am I doing wrong ?

Is the index no longer considered a column, using it without setting index will work but then join would not work at all.

What is the proper way to do so
[image: The error message]

Comment: Can you put in some sample data & print some of it ?

Comment: Also, can you share the full error message

Comment: I think once you set a column as index, you cannot reference it by column name. You can use `df.groupby(df.index)` instead. Again, you will get better response if you post your sample df and the expected results. Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Edited with both the sample data and the full error message

Comment: I think what @davidbilla suggested is correct. After setting a column as `index`, you won't be able to access it via column name.

Comment: Did you try using df.index in place of the index column 'Year'?

Comment: Using code like

act_min_wage = group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018]] works while we are still using the index column